# Wordpress Nginx 404

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect

I have a Wordpress instance running fine, and i have a directory on my server that needs to redirect users to another domain outside  the main server using a 302 rule. I add this on my server block and the redirection works fine:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location /lps {
     return 302 https://newdomain/$request_uri;
    }
}
```

but when i go to domain.com i got a 404 Not Found error.

I also try without luck.

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

Comment: i get error 500 when i try this

Comment: root block is missing. if you are using try_files directive. share your full nginx config. or refer basic vhost example here https://www.tecmint.com/create-nginx-server-blocks-in-ubuntu/

Comment: If your redirection for domain.com is working and newdomain.com isn't, you should probably show the nginx config for newdomain.com instead of domain.com.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Tt1YvCLa @ras

Comment: @Zaim my redirect from domain.com/lps to newdomain.com/lps works, but im missing my main site on domain.com

Comment: Try adding `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; }` before `location /lps { .. }`

Comment: @Zaim still error 500

Comment: As soon I add the server block my page goes 404, works when i remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve my issue with this:

```
http {                                                                                                                                                                                  
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;                                                                                                                                                
    default_type  application/octet-stream;                                                                                                                                             

    # Main Server Config                                                                                                                                                                                
    server {                                                                                                                                                                            
        listen       80;                                                                                                                                                                    
        server_name  localhost;                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                            
        root   /home/site/wwwroot;                                                                                                                                                          
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                        
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                        
        location / {                                                                                                                                                                        
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;                                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                            
        location /lps {                                                                                                                                                                     
            return 302 https://newdomain.net/$request_uri;                                                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                            
        location ~ \.php$ {                                                                                                                                                                 
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;                                                                                                                                    
            fastcgi_index index.php;                                                                                                                                                        
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;                                                                                                               
            include fastcgi_params;                                                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                            
        location = /50x.html {                                                                                                                                                              
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;                                                                                                                                                   
        }   
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

My Azure container have FastCGI and had to add the php instruction